# Binding TreeView to single object that contains many objects

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a binding like this:

```
<TreeView x:Name="QueuesTreeView" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MainWindowName, Path=QueueHierarchy, Mode=OneWay}" 
          BorderThickness="0"> ...
```

QueueHierarchy is:

```
public class QueueHierarchy
{
    public QueueHierarchy()
    {
        Children = new List<QueueHierarchy>();
    }
    public int QueueID { get; set; }
    public IList<QueueHierarchy> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I'm wondering how can I get a `TreeView` to bind to this? The problem with using the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` and `DataTemplate` is that the binding data type is the same... it's a `QueueHierarchy`.
So how could I differentiate between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to figure out how to give child `QueueHierarchy` items a different template than their parent, `HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate` should do the job:

```
<TreeView
    ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MainWindowName, Path=QueueHierarchy.Children}"
    >
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- Blue bkg only to show that it's a different template -->
                    <TextBlock Background="SkyBlue" Text="{Binding QueueID}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding QueueID}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

If the hierarchy is arbitrarily deep, you could make the child template hierarchical as well. If a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` has no `ItemTemplate` set, it will be used for its children, childrens' children etc. indefinitely.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding QueueID}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

You could also give the child template its own child template.

If you want your root collection item to be an item in the tree, I can think of a couple of options.

You could write a cheap and cheerful value converter that takes any given object and returns a collection containing only that object.

```
public class EnumerateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new List<object> { value };
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<TreeView
    ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MainWindowName, Path=QueueHierarchy, Converter={StaticResource EnumerateConverter}}"
    >
```

Or this would work:

```
private QueueHierarchy _qh;
public QueueHierarchy QueueHierarchy {
    get { return _qh; }
    set {
        if (_qh != value) {
            _qh = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(QueueHierarchy));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(QueueHierarchyRootLevel));
    }
}
public IEnumerable<QueueHierarchy> QueueHierarchyRootLevel {
    get { yield return QueueHierarchy; }
}
```

Or give `QueueHierarchy` a property that returns that same enumeration:

```
    public IEnumerable<QueueHierarchy> CollectionOfSelf {
        get { yield return this; }
    }
```

XAML:

```
<TreeView
    ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MainWindowName, Path=QueueHierarchy.CollectionOfSelf}"
    >
```

I'm starting to think the value converter idea is the most "correct MVVM" approach. You don't want your viewmodels to be worrying about this issue. It's really a view thing, and the converter confines the workaround to view-land.

Comment: The `Path=QueueHierarchy ` in the `TreeView`'s `ItemsSource` is binding to a single item. This isn't right, is it? It's not a collection.

Comment: I wondered about that. It's an easy fix, see `ItemsSource` binding in update.

Comment: This excludes the root item, but it happens to work for what I need (may not for someone else though).

Comment: @mariocatch Oh, duh, right. I'll add a workaround for that.